# Как преобразовать текст из DataFrame в нижний регистр?

Tags: python, pandas, текст

У меня есть данные которые я загрузил с помощью Pandas. Данные содержат различные столбцы, и один из них, это набор текстовых данных который представлен колонкой  `Description` и выглядит следующим образом:

```
df['Description']

  International Sales Manager London ****k  ****...                
  An ideal opportunity for an individual that ha...               
  Online Content and Brand Manager// Luxury Reta...     
  A great local marketleader is seeking a perman...               
  Registered Nurse / RGN  Nursing Home for Young...      
  Sales and Marketing Assistant will provide adm...
```

Нужно изменить текст на нижний шрифт. Как это сделать?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [How to convert string to lowercase in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6797984/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать [pandas.Series.str.lower()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html):

```
df['Description'].str.lower()
```

Пример:

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
                                         Description
0  International Sales Manager London ****k  ****...
1  An ideal opportunity for an individual that ha...
2  Online Content and Brand Manager// Luxury Reta...
3  A great local marketleader is seeking a perman...
4  Registered Nurse / RGN  Nursing Home for Young...
5  Sales and Marketing Assistant will provide adm...

In [7]: df['Description'] = df.Description.str.lower()

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
                                         Description
0  international sales manager london ****k  ****...
1  an ideal opportunity for an individual that ha...
2  online content and brand manager// luxury reta...
3  a great local marketleader is seeking a perman...
4  registered nurse / rgn  nursing home for young...
5  sales and marketing assistant will provide adm...
```

PS предпологается, что колонки со строками в Unicode кодировке! Все потециальные проблемы связанные с кодировкой, с использованием первой альфа версии Pandas, в которой, скорее всего отсутствует метод `.str.lower()` и прочие подобные "проблемы" считаю не связанными с данным вопросом и освещать их в ответе считаю неправильным - иначе это будет никому ненужная мини-энциклопедия...

Comment: Этот метод неверные результаты для не-ASCII данных возвращает. Нужно иметь ввиду, что следует текст сначала в Unicode преобразовать прежде чем `lower()` вызывать. Сравните: `'Абв'.lower()` (Python 2) и `u'Абв'.lower()`

Comment: @jfs, я исхожу из того, что Data Frame  __уже__ преобразован в unicode...

Comment: минус. Попробуйте на **Python 2** запустить как явно было сказано в моём комментарии: `pd.Series(['Abc', 'Абв']).str.lower()` -- этот код даёт неверный результат (`pandas.__version__ == '0.18.1'`, ` `sys.version_info[:2] == (2,7)`).

Comment: @jfs, используя CP1251 в Pandas вы обрекаете себя на ненужные проблемы, IMO

Comment: Я явно сказал: *"следует текст сначала в Unicode преобразовать прежде чем lower() вызывать"* — но мы не можем контролировать какие данные автор вопроса получает (идеально, конечно, весь текст всегда был бы представлен в виде Unicode строк, но это не всегда так). Ваш ответ обязан упомянуть, что он не работает, если данные заданы в виде байтовой строки. Ещё раз: я НЕ рекомендую использовать байты для представления текста.

Comment: @jfs, `Ваш ответ обязан упомянуть, что он не работает, если данные заданы в виде байтовой строки` - я считаю это не совсем правильным. По вашей логике такие ремарки надо делать в абсолютно всех ответах, где потенциально могут быть использованы байтовые строки - это, по-моему, перегружает ответ. И несет минимум полезной информации, о которой, к тому же, не спрашивали.

Comment: мысли читать я не умею, поэтому из информации в вопросе я не могу сделать вывод, что текст в виде Unicode в программе. Если у вас есть доказательство обратного, то я слушаю.

Comment: @jfs, вот, я как раз о чтении мыслей! С чего вы взяли, что у автора non-ASCII данные или что это он не знает как с таковыми данными работать?

Comment: представление текста в виде байт, закодированных в ASCII кодировке, не является ожидаемым представлением (2016 на дворе, Unicode стандарт уже достаточно взрослый чтобы своих детей иметь), поэтому если автор явно не указал что-то узкое и специальное, то по умолчанию следует предполагать представление, наиболее полезное для автора и будущих посетителей сайта: что текст представлен типами unicode, str в Питоне (с неизвестной кодировкой на Питоне 2).

Comment: @jfs, специально для вас обновил ответ ;)

Comment: Что вы передергиваете: где я про альфа версию говорил? Где доказательство, что ввод в Юникоде? (Если ваш ответ намеренно не поддерживает вероятный ввод, то предупреждение нужно *до* кода показывать, а не после). Специально для меня ничего делать не надо. Уберите мой ник из ответа.

Comment: @jfs, ник убрал. Какие доказательства? Проблема возникла у __вас__ (ладно бы еще у автора вопроса) ! А если бы у вас Python не запускался или Pandas не находился (да что угодно) - об этом тоже надо было бы в ответе для всех писать?

Comment: У меня лично такая проблема не возникла (опыт работы с текстом достаточный), а  упомянул  я её потому что она распространена и другие люди могут на неё напороться (из-за того что люди использовали байты, а не Юникод  для текста, и сопутствующих проблем, целую несовместимую версию Питона создали, чтобы исключить этот класс неявных ошибок (это не единственная причина, но фактически основная причина несовместимости)). Поэтому не нужно делать вид что такие проблемы в природе не встречаются и предлагать код, который *молча* может портить данные.

Comment: @jfs, в природе встречается огромное к-во проблем (я пытался привести примеры) и многие встречаются достаточно часто. Но я устал спорить... пусть будет по-вашему. ;) Советую также быть последовательным и заминусовать все ответы по работе со строками во всех питоновских библиотеках, которые явно не упоминают об "испорченных" данных ("из-за того что люди использовали байты, а не Юникод для текста") - на http://stackoverflow.com/ таких ответов ну оооочень много (я бы даже сказал абсолютное большинство) ;)

Comment: Ещё раз: проблема с текстом, представленным байтами, имеет самое прямое отношение к вопросу и является типичным случаем (например,если автор использует Питон 2 и есть байты из не ASCII диапазона такие как на этой самой странице) Это не вопрос вкуса, личного мнения итд — это вопрос фактов: как часто Питон 2 используется по сравнению с Питоном 3? Как часто не ASCII текст встречается? Конечно, для разных людей эти цифры могут быть разные, но вы можете сами прикинуть числа для посетителей данной страницы и решить стоит упоминать, что `bytes.lower()` не даст желаемого для текста результата или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы текст в маленькие буквы преобразовать, можно использовать `str.lower()` метод:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series([u'Abc', u'Абв'])
>>> s.str.lower()
0    abc
1    абв
dtype: object
```

Обратите внимание, что текст должен быть представлен в виде Unicode иначе для не-ASCII данных, представленных в виде байтовой строки (`bytes`), результат будет неверным:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(['Abc', 'Абв']) # Python 2
>>> s.str.lower()
0    abc
1    Абв
dtype: object
```

В общем случае, следует стараться использовать `unicode` тип для текста. Но это не всегда возможно, например, [HDFStore таблицы не поддерживают Юникод на Питоне 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20670901/4279).

Comment: HDFStore [уже должен поддерживать unicode](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11234) (лично я, правда не проверял, но у меня нет причин не верить Jeff'у - одному из основных разработчиков Pandas). Приведенный вами линк - это информация на конец 2013 года

Comment: @MaxU: этот билет не имеет отношения к моей цитате (в билете речь о Питоне 3 -- это просто баг), мой пример про Питон 2. В любом случае, мы не можем гарантировать, что всегда-всегда текст как Юникод представлен, поэтому следует знать что lower() на байтах *молча* неверный результат может вернуть.

Comment: `мы не можем гаранитировать, что всегда-всегда текст как Юникод представлен` - с этим трудно не согласиться. Кстати я попробовал сохранить data frame с non-ASCII колонкой в HDFStore - получил `PerformanceWarning: your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot map directly to c-types [inferred_type->unicode,key->axis0]`, но при этом все читается правильно

Comment: @MaxU какая версия Питона у вас?

Comment: специально проверял на Python 2 (последняя сборка Anakonda2)